# i trying to check last 4 hours for every 30 mnts. I'm trying to filter the rows based on the status and time

Tags: python, datetime, flask-sqlalchemy

i'm calling the below function for every 30 mnts using appscheduler to send mails. if've missed any mail inbetween due to server down or any other reason. i want to check last 4 hours for every 30 mnts. I'm trying to filter the rows based on the status and time.

I've tried the below approach but not worked for me.

assuming the the current time is '04:00'. so I'm trying to filter rows from db from last four hours(12:00 to 15:59)

```
from appscheduler.triggers.cron import CronTrigger
import time,datetime
def send_mail:
    current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M") #'04:00'
    current_date = int(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d"))
    # divided the clock for each four hours 
    #lst = [00:00 to 03:59, 4:00 to 7:59, 8:00 to 11:59, 12:00 to 15:59, 16:00 to 19:59, 20:00, 23:59]
    get_rmm_ids = db.session.query(
    table_name.id).filter(table_name.time_list == current_time and table_name.status = 'not 
    sent').all()

scheduler.add.job(func=send_mail_request, trigger=trigger30)
```

Comment: "mnts" means "minutes", I guess? Never seen that abbreviation before. That said, "not worked" is not a good error description. Also, I'm not sure if the use of a cron-style scheduler is a good approach when you want to do some things don't require scheduled executions, because that timespan where the cron schedule wasn't executed is already in the past. Further, it would help if you extracted a [mcve].

Comment: BTW: Your code has a race condition. Between the call to `time.strftime()` and the call to `datetime.now()`, the clock could advance to a new day. Use exactly one time source, I guess `datetime.now()` in your case. Then, call `strftime()` on in to retrieve separate strings with date and time.